# Extending native spell check

Tags: spellcheck

When I use the messages.app, messages I type are automagically corrected/replaced. How can I enable this feature across many more apps like Chrome for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system-wide spell-ckecker is accessed through System Prefs > Keyboard > Text... top right, 'Correct spelling automatically'...
 but I'm not sure Chrome doesn't just ignore it, it does most other things set system-wide.

If you look in the Edit menu in Safari, for instance, you'll see "Spelling and Grammar" & also "Substitutions"
Chrome only has part of the Spelling and Grammar menu, & Substitutions is missing entirely.

So, I think the **TL:DR** is Chrome can't/won't do this.